# Cannot get center of view inside dialog

Tags: android, android-animation

I have in essence two views inside a dialog. A `button`, and a `LinearLayout` which acts as a background. I'm trying to animate this `LinearLayout` with a `CircularReveal` from the center of the button so that it covers the whole dialog with a color.

This is the xml that I use as a dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ...

            <com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_enter_button"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:cpb_cornerRadius="1dp"
                app:cpb_textIdle="@string/login_sign_in"
                app:cpb_iconComplete="@drawable/ic_done_mini"
                app:cpb_selectorIdle="@color/morph_button_idle_colors"
                app:cpb_selectorComplete="@color/morph_button_complete_colors"
                app:cpb_colorIndicator="@color/colorAccent"
                app:cpb_colorIndicatorBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:cpb_colorProgress="@android:color/transparent"/>

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Background to be animated behind the CircularProgressButton -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_dialog_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

To do this animation I've used this approach, which I've already used it in other places in my app and works perfectly:

```
final CircularProgressButton enterButton = (CircularProgressButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_enter_button);

...

// This is called inside a listener, so the button is already drawn.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    int enterButtonX = (enterButton.getLeft()
            + enterButton.getRight()) / 2;

    int enterButtonY = ((int) enterButton.getY()
            + enterButton.getHeight()) / 2;

    View background = mAlertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_dialog_background);

    int radiusReveal = Math.max(background.getWidth()
            , background.getHeight());

    background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animator animator =
            android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(background
                    , enterButtonX
                    , enterButtonY
                    , 0
                    , radiusReveal);

    animator.setDuration(500);
    animator.setInterpolator(
            AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(LoginUI.this, R.anim.accelerator_interpolator));

    animator.start();
}
```

What's happening is that the coordinates are not even close to the button. In fact, the animation starts from the center of the dialog.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: you have the gravity center_horizontal and you have fixed margins horizontally...Why do you need them? also regarding the height since you have gravity bottom if the height is not wrap content it will not show it as you want

Comment: Can you post a simple project somewhere?

Comment: @TasdAqwe What do you mean? center_horizontal is maybe not necessary as I'm using match_parent, but still, it's shown as I want.

Comment: @azizbekian Sorry, I don't have access to an IDE right now, I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
public void startCircularReveal() {
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.revealView);
    final View startView = findViewById(R.id. button);
    int cx = (startView.getLeft() + startView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (startView.getTop() + startView.getBottom()) / 2;
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
    int finalRadius = Math.max(cy , view.getHeight() - cy);
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(200);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

Change the view startView to your button, and onAnimationEnd do whatever you want after the reveal is finished.

Now add this to the bottom of your xml :

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/revealView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/custom_theme_color"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:visibility="invisible">
</FrameLayout>
```

This view is where the reveal will be on top of ( named view at the start startCircularReveal() method ), hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any difference with my code, can you please tell me what you've changed?

Comment: Well I didn't check your code, but I wrote that code a time ago and it works fine, also as a background of the reveal I use a FrameLayout which is on top of every thing while you are using LinearLayout, are you sure the LinearLayout will be on top since the reveal will happen on top of it, btw did you try my code and didn't work?

Comment: I have a FrameLayout as container, with the button and the background inside, so the background will be on top of the button. It should not matter if the the background is a LinearLayout or a FrameLayout, right? BTW I can't try your code right now, but it does the same as mine apparently.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't matter if it's LinearLayour or FrameLayout, it only should be on top of everything at the moment of the reveal, any way you can apply my code easily, you only need to change both views at the beginning of the method and add the frameLayout at the bottom of your xml, good luck.

Comment: Will do, I think the problem is how I calculate the Y coordinate.

Comment: @cuoka I'm not sure but the reason could be because the getHeight and get getY  works relatively to the parent (LinearLayout) and not relatively to the FrameLayout, so it will not give you the right y location, you may try 2 solutions : change enterButtonY to  "int enterButtonY = ((int) enterButton. getTop() + enterButton. getBottom()) / 2;" or change the layout_height of the LinearLayout, ScrollView and FrameLayout to match_parent so the LinearLayout border touch the border of the screen.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.